# visual studio 2017 annotate (посмотреть автора строк/diff/commit_date из git или mercurial)

Tags: c#, git, intellij-idea, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Коллеги, я имел счастье перейти java ==> С#

В Intelij Idea была удобная фукция показа **автора** строк **подсветки цветом**, **можно глянуть diff** и **даты коммита**.

Собственно вопрос: как такое счастье получить в 2017 Студии?

(на скриншоте я ники затер. NDA такое NDA :)

выглядит вот так:

[image: выглядит вот так]

удобная всплывашка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

включается так (правый клик по номерам строк-->меню-->Annotate):

[image: правый клик по номерам строк-->меню-->Annotate]

версия студии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лучше вместо 2010 студии в тег поставили бы git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правый клик по коду, Source Control / Blame (Annotate)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]